# When to split baby Orchids

Tags: transplanting

I have an orchid that has two orchids going out of the stems that I believe I need to replant. I'm not sure if I should wait till after they bloom to transplant.

Comment: Hi Regina, a picture always helps.  You can do it by editing the question and clicking on the picture (mountain) icon.

Comment: And we need at least a name or a photo that helps us identify what we are talking about - orchids are the second-largest plant family with well over 700 to 1000 genera. And although only few of them are houseplants (and that’s already an assumption), we’d be more guessing than giving qualified advice. I have had keikis on two very different orchids, phalaenopsis hybrids and dendrobium nobile.

Comment: In nature, nobody removes them, but waiting for bloom means a year? I twist them off by hand once they start sending out roots. Dry for a day, then into small pots.